# User's OST File way larger than Mailbox

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have a user who's OST file is about 47GB. But her mailbox is 4.5GB. And yes, she has already hit the 50GB limit.  Why is the OST file so bloated? I have deleted her outlook profile and the ost file, then let it re-sync, but it still grows back to ~47GB! Couldn't find any large folders after searching, already emptied her deleted items. Tried turning off cache mode.. No help.

Only thing I have not done yet is compacting.  Will compacting really get rid of 40GB of empty space?  And from what I read, it takes hours & hours to complete? @47GB Probably needs to be a Friday night project then.

I know this problem is all over the web but I have tried just about everything I found.  Hoping someone has another suggestion.  Thanks!

Outlook 2010, Win7 / Exchange 2010

Comment: If she access through Outlook to multiple shared mailboxes, than they are all stored in her OST. Try removing those mailboxes.

Comment: There are no shared mailboxes

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out...
Unchecked the "Download shared folders" under the Cached Exchange Mode Settings.  Not it sits at 6GB.